# How to design and structure a program that uses Actors

Tags: ruby, concurrency, erlang, actor, celluloid

From [Joe Armstrong's dissertation](http://www.erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf), he specified that an Actor-based program should be designed by following three steps. The thing is, I don't understand how the steps map to a real world problem or how to apply them. Here's Joe's original suggestion.

> 1. We identify all the truly concurrent activities in our real world activity.
> 2. We identify all message channels between the concurrent activities.
> 3. We write down all the messages which can flow on the different message channels.
>    Now we write the program. The structure of the program should exactly follow the structure of the problem. Each real world concurrent activity should be mapped onto exactly one concurrent process in our programming language. If there is a 1:1 mapping of the problem onto the program we say that the program is isomorphic to the problem.
>
> It is extremely important that the mapping is exactly 1:1. The reason for this is that it minimizes the conceptual gap between the problem and the solution. If this mapping is not 1:1 the program will quickly degenerate, and become difficult to understand. This degeneration is often observed when non-CO languages are used to solve concurrent problems. Often the only way to get the program to work is to force several independent activities to be controlled by the same language thread or process. This leads to an inevitable loss of clarity, and makes the programs subject to complex and irreproducible interference errors.

I think #1 is fairly easy to figure out. It's #2 (and 3) where I get lost. To illustrate my frustration I stubbed out a small service available in this gist ([Ruby service with callbacks](http://gist.github.com/chuckremes/6243575)).

Looking at that example service I can see how to answer #1. We have 5 concurrent services.

1. Start
2. LoginGateway
3. LogoutGateway
4. Stop
5. Subscribe

Some of those services don't work (or shouldn't) depending on the state the service is in. If the service hasn't been Started, then Login/Logout/Subscribe make no sense. Does this kind of state information have any relevance to Joe's 3 steps?

Anyway, given the example/mock service in that gist, I'm wondering how someone would go about designing a program to wrap this service up in an Actory fashion. I would just like to see a list of guidelines on how to apply Joe's 3 steps. Bonus points for writing some code (any language).

Answer (score 9):

Generally, when structuring an application to use actors you have to identify the concurrent features of your application, which can be tricky to get the hang of. You identify 5 concurrent "services":

1. Start
2. LoginGateway
3. LogoutGateway
4. Stop
5. Subscribe

1, 4 and 5 seem to be types of messages that can flow through the system, 2 and 3 I'm not sure how to describe. Your gist is rather large and not *super* clear to me, but it looks like you've got some kind of message queue system. The actions a **User** can take are:

1. Log in to the system
2. Log out of the system
3. Subscribe to a **Queue** of messages

I'll assume logging in and out requires some auth step. I'll assume further that if the user fails the auth step their connection is broken but that creating a connection is not sufficient authentication.

The actions the **System** takes are:

1. Handling **User** actions
2. Routing messages to subscribers of a **Queue**

If that's not broadly true, let me know and I'll change this answer. (I'll assume that the messages that get sent to users are *not* generated by users but are an intrinsic part of the **System**; maybe we're discussing a monitoring service.) Anyhow, what is concurrent here? A few things:

1. **Users** act independently of one another
2. **Queues** have separate states

An actor based architecture represents each concurrent entity as its own process. The **User** is a finite state machine which authenticates, subscribes to a queue, alternatively receives messages and subscribes to more queues and eventually disconnects. In Erlang/OTP we'd represent this by a [gen_fsm](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/fsm.html). The **User** process carries all the state needed to interact with the client which, if we're exposing a service over a network, would be a socket.

Authentication implies that the **System** is itself a 'process', though, more likely than not it's really a *collection* of processes which in Erlang/OTP we call an [application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html). I digress. For simplification we'll assume that **System** is itself a single process which has some well-defined protocol and a state that keeps user credentials. **User** logins are, then, a well-defined message from *a* **User** process to *the* **System** process and the response therefrom. If there were no authentication we'd have no need for a **System** process as the only state related to a **User** would be a socket.

The careful reader will ask where do we accept socket connections for each **User**? Ah, good question. There's another concurrent entity in not mentioned, which we'll call here the **Listener**. It's another process that *only* listens for connections, creates a **User** for each new established socket and hands over ownership to the new **User** process, then loops *back* to listen.

The **Queue** is also a finite state machine. From its start state it accepts **User** subscription requests via a well-defined protocol, broadcasts messages to subscribers or accepts unsubscribe requests from **User** processes. This implies that the **Queue** has an internal store of **User** processes, the details of which are very dependent on language and need. In Erlang/OTP, for example, each **Queue** process would be a [gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) which stored **User** process ids--or PIDs--in a list and for each message to transmit simply did a multi-send to each **User** process in the list.

(In Erlang/OTP we'd user supervisors to ensure that processes stay alive and are restarted on death, which simplifies greatly the amount of work an Erlang developer has to do to ensure reliability in an actor-based architecture.)

Basically, to restate what Joe wrote, actor based architecture boils down to these points:

- identify concurrent entities in the system and represent them in the implementation by processes,
- decide how your processes will send messages (a primitive operation in Erlang/OTP, but something that has to be implemented explicitly in C or Ruby) and
- create well-defined protocols *between* entities in the system which hide state modification.

It's been said that the Internet is the world's most successful actor based architecture and, really, that's not far off.